# Add custom hidden checkout field with a default value in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

How to add custom field in checkout Woocommerce with hidden type and default value?

please check below my code:

```
function pord_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['quickbook'] = array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'label'     => __('Purchase Order Number', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'  => _x('Purchase Order Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','pord_checkout_fields');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden type doesn't exist buy default for woocommerce form fields… But you can create it.

- The first function will create that hidden field type.
- The 2nd function will add this hidden custom field (where you will set the value)
- The third function will display this value in order edit page

Here is the code:

```
// Create hidden checkout field type
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_hidden', 'create_checkout_hidden_field_type', 5, 4 );
function create_checkout_hidden_field_type( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    return '<input type="hidden" name="'.esc_attr($key).'" id="'.esc_attr($args['id']).'" value="'.esc_attr($args['default']).'" />';
}

// Add custom hidden billing checkout field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_billing_fields' );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ){

    ## HERE set the value (for this hidden checkout field)
    $value = "The value";

    $fields['billing']['billing_quickbook'] = array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'label'     => __('Purchase Order Number', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'  => _x('Purchase Order Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'default'   => $value, // The custom field value
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Display the field value on the admin order edit page (after billing address)
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_field_in_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_field_in_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Quickbook').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_quickbook', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **USAGE** *(RETRIEVING THE VALUE)*:
>
> To get the value from the Order ID `$order_id`, you will use *(if needed)*:
>
> ```
> $value = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_quickbook', true );
> ```

This code is tested and works in WooCommerce 3+.

---

Official developer documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Answer (score -1):

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'My new placeholder';
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'My new label';
     return $fields;
}
```